# rdate for Windows 2008

Tags: untagged

I need a command line tool that adjusts the time of a Windows 2008 server, using an internet clock. The purpose is to adjust the time in a script, when other apps from that script are not running.

It is not an option to use the built-in NTP service because that makes some apps on this server fail - note, that this server is used in an industrial environment with no PCs on the network and no Windows update or similar applied.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would want to do this with a script.  Your best bet is to set an authoritative time service.  See this technet article.   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794823(WS.10).aspx

EDIT due to more information in the question and comments.  There is no way you can prevent the server from adjusting the clock if it's getting time from another source.  It seems that your best solution is to install a time server.  I do this on my network because we don't have a connection to the internet.  We currently use Symmetricom S250 devices synced to a GPS signal.  Also note that the Windows OS does not support very accurate time but there are software bundles to fix that.

Link to set an external NTP server:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042

Link explaining the limits of Windows time service:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322

Comment: The Windows 2008 server is an industrial computer, that is on a firewalled network that does not have any PCs attached. It is not part of a domain or anything similar. Your link does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you want the script to do, and more importantly, why you simply don't want to point your server at pool.ntp.org.

Comment: I want to point the server at pool.ntp.org or similar, but I want to be 100% sure that the system time does not change unless I ask it to. For our industrial purpose, this is very important.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerShell:  sync system time with Internet time server](http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2009/03/30/powershell-sync-system-time-with-internet-time-server.aspx)